# Ruby: Make strings from objects given the sort as a value

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting, object

Looking for some insight on how to go about creating a string in a new object given the sorted values for each id.

**Given data:**

```
[
 {"id":14, "sort":1, "content":"9"},
 {"id":14, "sort":4, "content":"5"},
 {"id":14, "sort":2, "content":"1"},
 {"id":14, "sort":3, "content":"0"},
 {"id":15, "sort":4, "content":"4"},
 {"id":15, "sort":2, "content":"1"},
 {"id":15, "sort":1, "content":"3"},
 {"id":15, "sort":3, "content":"3"},
 {"id":16, "sort":1, "content":"8"},
 {"id":16, "sort":3, "content":"4"},
 {"id":16, "sort":2, "content":"4"},
 {"id":16, "sort":4, "content":"9"}
]
```

**Desired Output:**

```
[
 {"id":14, "concated_value":"9105"},
 {"id":15, "concated_value":"3134"},
 {"id":16, "concated_value":"8449"}
]
```

Comment: in the desired output, why does id 14 appear twice? is that a typo?

Comment: This is a case for `reduce` and some pretty straight-forward string concatenation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a basic solution that together as `{ id => grouped_content }`:

```
ids_and_content = data.group_by { |d| d[:id] }.transform_values do |value_array| 
  value_array.sort_by { |hash| hash[:sort] }.map { |hash| hash[:content] }.join
end
```

Then, to transform this into your desired format:

```
ids_and_content.map { |id, content| { id: id, concated_value: content } }
```

That works to give your desired output, and you could always stop at the first step if it suits your needs.

Basically, it groups the values by their `:id`, sorts the values by `:sort, joins their`:content` in the desired format, and then maps to a new array with your desired keys.

Hope that helps - let me know how you get on or if you have any questions.

Comment: Welcome - happy to help out :)

Comment: If I wanted to pass through another key/value pair, how would I pass that down through ids_and_content? 

`[...{"id":14, "concated_value":"9105", "foo": "bar" }, ..]`

Comment: Add it to the `map` statement, everything will still be available there. E.G. `.map { |id, content| { id: id, concated_value: content, foo: "bar"  } }`. That should do it - if not, feel free to pop this in a new question and `@` me, happy to help further.

Comment: New question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51330262/ruby-passing-down-key-value-after-transforming-objects-in-array)