# Ruby: Passing down key/value after transforming objects in array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

**Given data:**

```
data = [
 {"id":14, "sort":1, "content":"9", foo: "2022"},
 {"id":14, "sort":4, "content":"5", foo: "2022"},
 {"id":14, "sort":2, "content":"1", foo: "2022"},
 {"id":14, "sort":3, "content":"0", foo: "2022"},
 {"id":15, "sort":4, "content":"4", foo: "2888"},
 {"id":15, "sort":2, "content":"1", foo: "2888"},
 {"id":15, "sort":1, "content":"3", foo: "2888"},
 {"id":15, "sort":3, "content":"3", foo: "2888"},
 {"id":16, "sort":1, "content":"8", foo: "3112"},
 {"id":16, "sort":3, "content":"4", foo: "3112"},
 {"id":16, "sort":2, "content":"4", foo: "3112"},
 {"id":16, "sort":4, "content":"9", foo: "3112"}
]
```

Got the contents concatenated by their `sort` and `ids` with:

```
formatted = data.group_by { |d| d[:id]}.transform_values do |value_array|
  value_array.sort_by { |b| b[:sort] }
             .map     { |c| c[:content] }.join
end

puts formatted
#=> {14=>"9105", 15=>"3134", 16=>"8449"}
```

I know that `foo` exists inside `value_array` but wondering how can I include `foo` to exist inside the `formatted` variable so I can map through it to get the desired output or if it's possible?

**Desired Output:**

```
[
 {"id":14, "concated_value":"9105", foo: "2022"},
 {"id":15, "concated_value":"3134", foo: "2888"},
 {"id":16, "concated_value":"8449", foo: "3112"}
]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `:foo` is unique to `:id`. You can do this as follows:

```
data.group_by {|h| h[:id]}.map do |_,sa| 
  sa.map(&:dup).sort_by {|h| h.delete(:sort) }.reduce do |m,h| 
     m.merge(h) {|key,old,new| key == :content ? old + new : old } 
  end.tap {|h| h[:concated_value] = h.delete(:content) }
end  
#=> [
# {"id":14, foo: "2022", "concated_value":"9105"},
# {"id":15, foo: "2888", "concated_value":"3134"},
# {"id":16, foo: "3112", "concated_value":"8449"}
# ]
```

- First we group by id. `group_by {|h| h[:id]}`
- Then we dup the hashes in the groups (so as not to destory the original). `map(&:dup)`
- Then we sort by sort and delete it at the same time. `.sort_by {|h| h.delete(:sort) }`
- Then we merge the groups together and concatenate the content key only. 
  `m.merge(h) {|key,old,new| key == :content ? old + new : old }`
- Then we just change the key for `content` to `concated_value` `tap {|h| h[:concated_value] = h.delete(:content) }`

Comment: Thanks so much for the thorough explanation! Just one additional question. Say I wanted to use `reject` on some items from `:content` where `.length > 1`. Would that work in this situation?

Comment: Sure just reject them up from `data.reject {|h| h[:content].length > 1 }.group_by#...`

Answer (score 2):

We can use first value from value_array to get our :id & :foo values

```
formatted = data.group_by { |d| d[:id]}.values.map do |value_array|
  concated_value = value_array.sort_by { |b| b[:sort] }
                              .map     { |c| c[:content] }.join
  value_array.first.slice(:id, :foo)
             .merge concated_value: concated_value
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a good usecase for `reduce`, since after grouping you need first to get rid of the ID in the resulting `[ID, VALUES]` array from `group_by` and just return a reduced version of the `VALUES` part - this can all be done without any `ActiveSupport` etc. dependencies:

```
data
  .group_by{ |d| d[:id] } # Get an array of [ID, [VALUES]]
  .reduce([]) do |a, v| # Reduce it into a new empty array
    # Append a new hash to the new array
    a << {
      id: v[1].first[:id], # Just take the ID of the first entry
      foo: v[1].first[:foo], # Dito for foo
      concatenated: v[1] 
        .sort_by{ |s| s[:sort] } # now sort all hashes by its sort key
        .collect{ |s| s[:content] } # collect the content
        .join # and merge it into a string
    }
  end
```

Output:

```
[{:id=>14, :foo=>"2022", :concatenated=>"9105"}, 
 {:id=>15, :foo=>"2888", :concatenated=>"3134"}, 
 {:id=>16, :foo=>"3112", :concatenated=>"8449"}]
```

**EDIT**

I had some other approach in mind when i started to write the previous solution, `reduce` was not really necessary, since the size of the array after `group_by` does not change, so a `map` is sufficient.

But while rewriting the code, i was thinking that creating a new hash with all the keys and copying all the values from the first hash within `VALUES` was a bit too much work, so it would be easier to just reject the overhead keys:

```
keys_to_ignore = [:sort, :content]

data
  .group_by{ |d| d[:id] } # Get an array of [ID, [VALUES]]
  .map do |v| 
    v[1]
      .first # Take the first hash from [VALUES]
      .merge({'concatenated': v[1] # Insert the concatenated values
        .sort_by{ |s| s[:sort] } # now sort all hashes by its sort key
        .collect{ |s| s[:content] } # collect the content
        .join # and merge it into a string
      })
      .select { |k, _| !keys_to_ignore.include? k }
  end
```

Output

```
[{:id=>14, :foo=>"2022", :concatenated=>"9105"}, 
 {:id=>15, :foo=>"2888", :concatenated=>"3134"}, 
 {:id=>16, :foo=>"3112", :concatenated=>"8449"}]
```

Online demo [here](https://repl.it/repls/DesertedDetailedSale)

Comment: This is super clean, love it. Thanks for showing me `collect`

Comment: `reduce` was unnecessary, a `map` would have been sufficient - i also added another approach to solve this, in case there would be a lot more values to return from the original hashes.

Answer (score 1):

This will work even without Rails:

```
$irb> formatted = []
$irb> data.sort_by!{|a| a[:sort]}.map {|z| z[:id]}.uniq.each_with_index { |id, index| formatted << {id: id, concated_value: data.map{|c| (c[:id] == id ? c[:content] : nil)}.join, foo: data[index][:foo]}}
$irb> formatted
[{:id=>14, :concated_value=>"9105", :foo=>"2022"}, 
{:id=>15, :concated_value=>"3134", :foo=>"2888"},
{:id=>16, :concated_value=>"8449", :foo=>"3112"}]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
data.sort_by { |h| h[:sort] }.
     each_with_object({}) do |g,h| h.update(g[:id]=>{ id: g[:id],
       concatenated_value: g[:content].to_s, foo: g[:foo] }) {  |_,o,n|
         o.merge(concatenated_value: o[:concatenated_value]+n[:concatenated_value]) }
     end.values
  #=> [{:id=>14, :concatenated_value=>"9105", :foo=>"2022"},
  #    {:id=>15, :concatenated_value=>"3134", :foo=>"2888"},
  #    {:id=>16, :concatenated_value=>"8449", :foo=>"3112"}]
```

This uses the form of [Hash#update](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-update) (aka `merge!`) that employs a block to determine the values of keys (here the value of `:id`) that are present in both hashes being merged. See the doc for the description of the three block variables (here `_`, `o` and `n`).

Note the receiver of `values` (at the end) is the following.

```
{ 14=>{ :id=>14, :concatenated_value=>"9105", :foo=>"2022" },
  15=>{ :id=>15, :concatenated_value=>"3134", :foo=>"2888" },
  16=>{ :id=>16, :concatenated_value=>"8449", :foo=>"3112" } }
```